# How to use transactional DatastoreIO

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I’m using DatastoreIO from my streaming Dataflow pipeline and getting an error when writing an entity with the same key.

```
2016-12-10T22:51:04.385Z: Error:   (af00222cfd901860): Exception: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: A non-transactional commit may not contain multiple mutations affecting the same entity., code=INVALID_ARGUMENT
```

If I use a random number in the key then things work but I need to update the same key so is there a transactional way to do this using DataStoreIO?

```java
static class CreateEntityFn extends DoFn<KV<String, Tile>, Entity> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

  private final String namespace;
  private final String kind;

  CreateEntityFn(String namespace, String kind) {
    this.namespace = namespace;
    this.kind = kind;
  }

  public Entity makeEntity(String key, Tile tile) {
    Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder();
    Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey(kind, key );
    if (namespace != null) {
      keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespaceId(namespace);
    }
    entityBuilder.setKey(keyBuilder.build());
    entityBuilder.getMutableProperties().put("tile", makeValue(tile.toString()).build()); 
    return entityBuilder.build();   
  }

  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) { 
    String key = c.element().getKey();
    // this works    key = key.concat(":" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    c.output(makeEntity(key, c.element().getValue()));
  }
}

...

...
 inputData = pipeline
                .apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic(pubsubTopic));
 windowedDataStreaming = inputData
                .apply(Window.<String>into(
                      SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(15))
                                    .every(Duration.standardSeconds(31))));


                             ...
                             ...
                             ...
 //Create a Datastore entity 
 PCollection<Entity> siteTileEntities = tileSiteKeyed
      .apply(ParDo.named("CreateSiteEntities").of(new CreateEntityFn(options.getNamespace(), options.getKind())));       

 // write site tiles to datastore
 siteTileEntities
      .apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(options.getDataset()));

 // Run the pipeline
 pipeline.run();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. Could you also share how you're constructing `inputData`? I'm particularly interested in the Datastore `Query` object.

Comment: I don't have a Datastore Query object.  I'm reading data from a pubsub.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code snippet doesn't explain how `tileSiteKeyed` is created. Presumably it's a `PCollection<KV<String, Tile>`, but if it might have duplicate `String` keys, that would explain the issue.

Generally a `PCollection<KV<K, V>>` may contain multiple KV pairs with the same key. If you'd like to ensure unique keys per window, you can use a `GroupByKey` to do that. That will give you a `PCollection<KV<K, Iterable<V>>>` with unique keys per window. Then augment `CreateEntityFn` to take an `Iterable<Tile>` and create a single mutation with the changes you need to make.

Comment: Thanks very much I think that is the issue.  I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that Cloud Datastore received a `Commit` request with two mutations for the same key (i.e. it tries to insert the same entity twice or modify the same entity twice).

You can avoid the error by only including one mutation per key per `Commit` request.

Comment: It is running in a streaming Dataflow pipeline and I'm assuming that more than one worker at a time might be writing the same key.  My question is asking for a way around this.

Comment: Ah, this might be related to the way Dataflow does batching under the hood. Would you be able to share a code sample: specifically, the query you're running and the transforms?